# spring boot login application

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:429)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.csi.app1.ApplicationDemo1.ApplicationDemo1Application.main(ApplicationDemo1Application.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:446)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.asUnmodifiableOrderedSet(SpringApplication.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getListeners(SpringApplication.java:1236)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.<init>(EventPublishingRunListener.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: the only useful information I get out of your post is: "Cannot instantiate interface". Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hi! Please add more info or if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Roshni, it seems somewhere in your code you are writing,

```
YOUR_INTERFACE_NAME objectname = new YOUR_INTERFACE_NAME();
```

means you are trying to create new instance of an interface.

Please check and remove that line, and insted implement that interface in a class and then initialize the class.